# Why is there a gap on each div that I am placing on the infinite slider?

Tags: jquery

I am doing my own slider. What I'm trying to do it to after the first div reached a certain position, I changed its position by calculating the position of the last div and adding its width.

Seems to be working find until you see a gap between images.

Here is a link: http://labs.lesevades.com/opc

Here is my code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    animateCarousel();          
},5000);

function animateCarousel() {
    $('div', section).animate({ 
        'left':'-=780' 
        }, 2500, 'easeInExpo', testMovement);
}   

function testMovement() {
    if($(this).position().left < -781) {
        var lastPos = $('div', section).last().position().left;
        var totalLastPos = lastPos+781; 
        $(this).css('left', totalLastPos+'px');     
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes its easier to use a cassette with your sliders within it..

```
<div class='overflow-hidden'>
  <div class='cassette'>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
    <div class='slide'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now just slide your cassette div to the position you'd like...
you dont have to calculate individual positions and move all the divs

here's something i did a while back ... might help you...

https://github.com/drmjo/urbancoyote-slider

cheers...